# Locked out of cifs mounted storage

Tags: linux, mount, cifs

I've been using this line in /etc/fstab for mounting a storage device to my host:

> //url.to-my-storage.com/mystorage /mnt/backup cifs
> iocharset=utf8,rw,credentials=/etc/backup-credentials.txt,uid=1000,gid=1000,file_mode=0660,dir_mode=0770
> 0 0

I was mounting it to another host, and I ran this to protect the files from change through the new host:

> chmod -R 444 /mnt/backup

(I tried to protect the storage from writing from this host, which turned out to change the mode of all the storage files)

I assume the missing **executable** permissions  what causing me this:

> $ sudo mount -a
>
> mount error(13): Permission denied
>
> Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)

I tried unmounting and mounting again, that didn't help, got the same permission error when using the mount command.

ls the dir shows this:

> $ ls -la /mnt/backup
>
> ?????????? ? ? ? ? ? backup

HELP !

Answer (score 0):

### Dismounting a "Locked Out" Network Drive

To dismount a "locked out" network drive, you can try to force the unmount:

```
umount -f -t cifs /mnt/backup
```

If you are having trouble dismounting a drive, make sure that you don't have a console open somewhere where the current working directory (CWD) on the drive which you are trying to dismount, or have a file open in an editor or player somewhere or such.

### Properly Mounting a Network Drive

You should add your permissions in your mount options rather than trying to apply them afterwards.  You would want to replace these mount options:

```
rw,file_mode=0660,dir_mode=0770
```

with

```
ro
```

Currently you are mounting your CIFS drive as read-write (`rw`), giving files read-write permission (`file_mode=0660`) and directories read-write-execute (`dir_mode=0770`).  Simply mounting the drive as read-only (`ro`) should suffice.  (If you do need to fine tune the file and dir modes, rather use `umask`.)

I would also advise you to double check whether you are using `uid` and `gid` correctly: if the user ID or group ID used gets deleted, that could also lead to problems.

### References

- https://linux.die.net/man/8/mount
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system_permissions
- https://oracletechdba.blogspot.com/2017/06/umount-lsof-warning-cant-stat-cifs-file.html
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/40527234/171993